# Unity/PowerUI, Arabic text renders differently (rendered chars are not the same as input)

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, localization, arabic, unity-powerui

I'm facing a problem with rendering arabic text, via [PowerUI framework](https://powerui.kulestar.com/). The text is passed as:

```
ui.htlm = mystring;
```

Following is `mystring`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content - Type" content="text / html; charset = UTF - 8"/>
<meta name="languages" content="ar"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:95%;height:450px;margin:0 auto;">
    <p style="color:red;">إن الجمال الذي تستمتع به هو الجمال الذي بداخلك</p>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

What it should look like:

إن الجمال الذي تستمتع به هو الجمال الذي بداخلك

Output in Unity:

[image: Unity output]

Problem is, that the text is not rendering properly (characters are not the same).

**What is the cause? Is there any font issues? Or is it due to Unicode?**